# Has anyone studied anomalous supersymmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9612057) (and others), the authors study a supersymmetric model where the supercharge suffers an ABJ anomaly.  Has anyone studied a supersymmetry with a 't Hooft anomaly (gauging the supersymmetry results in a sick theory)?

Comment: Sure. See [Abbott, Grisaru, Schnitzer, 1977](http://neurotheory.columbia.edu/Larry/AbbottPR77a.pdf), so then [PRD](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.2995) and voluminous citations thereto.